# matplotlib not continuing lines after NaN's

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have an array slice:

```
array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, None, 4.0, None, 5.0, None, 6.0, None], dtype=object)
```

which when plotted looks like [image: THIS]

How do I get the dotted/connecting lines to continue after the None values? I tried changing the data type from objects to floats using astype and the None's are replaced with nan's but it made no difference, I also tried a masked array using np.where(np.isnan()) etc. but it didn't make a difference. My plotting command is very simply:

```
plt.plot(x, array, 'ro--')
```

where x is a numpy array.

Comment: The "array" you show can not correspond to the axes you show. Is it an array of indices such as that from a numpy.where ?

Comment: Jblasco - apologies, I changed the values so the array wasn't cumbersome to read.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the correct behavior, `mpl` tries to connect adjacent points.  If you have points with a `nan` on either side, there is no valid way to connect them to anything.

If you want to just ignore your `nan`s when plotting, then strip them out

```
ind = ~np.isnan(np.asarray(data.astype(float)))
plt.plot(np.asarray(x)[ind], np.asarray(data)[ind], 'ro--')
```

All the `asarray` are just to be sure the example will work, same with the `astype`

also, it is really bad practice to use variable names that shadow (both in terms of python resolution and in terms of semantic) classes (like array) or common functions.

Comment: tcaswell - thanks for your answer. In my code the array is not named array, I just changed it to that here so it was obvious what it was. It seems that changing the name and values of the array has caused more confusion than it solved :). Cheers again.