# Remove NaN values from dataframe without fillna or Interpolate

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a dataset:

```
           367235   419895  992194
1999-01-11  8   5   1
1999-03-23  NaN 4   NaN
1999-04-30  NaN NaN 1
1999-06-02  NaN 9   NaN
1999-08-08  2   NaN NaN
1999-08-12  NaN 3   NaN
1999-08-17  NaN NaN 10
1999-10-22  NaN 3   NaN
1999-12-04  NaN NaN 4
2000-03-04  2   NaN NaN
2000-09-29  9   NaN NaN
2000-09-30  9   NaN NaN
```

When I plot it, using `plt.plot(df, '-o')` I get this:

[image: output from plotting dataframe]

But what I would like is for the datapoints from each column to be connected in a line, like so:

[image: desired output from plotting dataframe]

I understand that matplotlib does not connect datapoints that are separate by NaN values. I looked at all the options [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.8.1/missing_data.html) for dealing with missing data, but all of them would essentially misrepresent the data in the dataframe.  This is because each value within the dataframe represents an incident; if I try to replace the NaNs with scalar values or use the interpolate option, I get a bunch of points that are not actually in my dataset. Here's what interpolate looks like:

`df_wanted2 = df.apply(pd.Series.interpolate)`

[image]

If I try to use `dropna` I'll lose entire rows\columns from the dataframe, and these rows hold valuable data.

Does anyone know a way to connect up my dots?  I suspect I need to extract individual arrays from the datasframe and plot them, as is the advice given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18430921/matplotlib-not-continuing-lines-after-nans#18430974), but this seems like a lot of work (and my actual dataframe is much bigger.)  Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use `interpolate` method with parameter `'index'`

```
df.interpolate('index').plot(marker='o')
```

[image]

***alternative answer***

`plot` after `iteritems`

```
for _, c in df.iteritems():
    c.dropna().plot(marker='o')
```

[image]

---

***extra credit***
only interpolate from first valid index to last valid index for each column

```
for _, c in df.iteritems():
    fi, li = c.first_valid_index(), c.last_valid_index()
    c.loc[fi:li].interpolate('index').plot(marker='o')
```

[image]

Comment: the second answer worked great because the lines did not go to the end of the plot - many thanks!

Comment: IMO, this answer would be improved if you moved the "alternative answer" first (or even made it the only one). The other two approaches result in misleading plots, since they add apparent data points that are not actually present in the OP's data.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen good points. I'll edit later and make more clear. Thx for feedback

Answer (score 4):

Try iterating through with `apply` and then inside the apply function drop the missing values

```
def make_plot(s):
    s.dropna().plot()

df.apply(make_plot)
```

Comment: Thanks. Choose @pirsquared answer as it is better and more complete

Answer (score 3):

An alternative would be to outsource the `NaN` handling to the graph libary Plotly using its [`connectgaps`](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#scatter-connectgaps) function.

```
import plotly
import pandas as pd

txt = """367235 419895 992194
1999-01-11 8 5 1
1999-03-23 NaN 4 NaN
1999-04-30 NaN NaN 1
1999-06-02 NaN 9 NaN
1999-08-08 2 NaN NaN
1999-08-12 NaN 3 NaN
1999-08-17 NaN NaN 10
1999-10-22 NaN 3 NaN
1999-12-04 NaN NaN 4
2000-03-04 2 NaN NaN
2000-09-29 9 NaN NaN
2000-09-30 9 NaN NaN"""

data_points = [line.split(' ') for line in txt.splitlines()[1:]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data_points)

data = list()
for i in range(1, len(df.columns)):
    data.append(plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(
        x = df.iloc[:,0].tolist(),
        y = df.iloc[:,i].tolist(),
        mode = 'line',
        connectgaps = True
    ))

fig = dict(data=data)
plotly.plotly.sign_in('user', 'token')
plot_url = plotly.plotly.plot(fig)
```

[image]