# Keep the gap between two datasets in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two datasets

```
firstX = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] # X Axis 
firstY = [10, 10, 20, 30, 40, 60, 70] # Y Axis
secondX = [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15] # X Axis
secondY = [40, 20, 60, 11, 77, 12, 54] # Y Axis
```

I want to plot these two datasets in the same chart but without connecting them together. As you can see, there is a disconnection between them (in X axis, 7 and 8 are missing). When I concat them, matplotlib will try to connect the last point of the first dataset `(6, 70)` with the first point of the second dataset `(9, 40)`. I would like to know how to avoid this behavior

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38178587/1025391 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/18430921/1025391

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just plot them individually. If they're sublists of a list, e.g. `X = [[X1], [X2]]`, `Y = [[Y1], [Y2]]`, you can loop over them.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
for i in range(len(X)):
    plt.plot(X[i], Y[i])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of concatenating the datasets, you can call the plot command two times, plotting two times to the same axes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(firstX, firstY)
ax.plot(secondX, secondY)
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand your question, this should work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
plt.plot(firstX, firstY, c='b')
plt.plot(secondX, secondY, c='b')
plt.show
```